# Test if object gets instantiated with correct argument value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm doing unit testing for C# code with Moq and Nunit and I want to test the simplified method below. In terms of unit testing, I think I shouldn't check the foo value because FooClass might be subject to change and subsequently break my test in the future. So the least I could do is verify that everything gets initialized and called correctly, that is, someContainer gets the correct values and FooClass gets someContainer and not some other MyContainer instance. How do I do that? Is this (unit) testing approach correct?

```
public MyClass
{
   ...
   public bool MyMethod(int a, int b, int c, out FooClass foo)
   {
      var someContainer = new MyContainer{
         A = a,
         B = b,
         C = c
      };

      foo = new FooClass(someContainer,1,2,3);

      ...
      return true;
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test that `foo` gets `someContainer` because `someContainer` is only accessible from inside the method.  An appropriate test for that method would be that `foo` contains `a`, `b` and `c` in the right places and that it contains some `MyContainer` object.  It would be a unit test of that `FooClass` constructor that tested that the `FooClass` object contained the correct `MyContainer` object.

If your `FooClass` is going to change then presumably your `MyMethod` is going to change too, so any tests of `MyMethod` would have to change too.  The fact that it breaks your test is good because it means that you need to look at that method and make sure that the method does what you want and that you're testing that it does what you want.  You should either write proper tests now for the method as it is now or don't bother writing any tests at all until `FooClass` is finalised.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this (unit) testing approach correct?

If you're wanting to mock out dependencies so you can test a specific unit of your code (e.g. `MyClass` in your example), then you need to look at composing your code into services that take care of the different responsibilities. In your example your `MyMethod` has several responsibilities:

1. Creating a new `MyContainer`
2. Creating a new `FooClass`
3. Providing the `MyContainer` instance that `FooClass` should be created with.

To satisfy your desire to test that `MyMethod` passes a particular `MyContainer` into the `FooClass` you could separate responsibilities 1 and 2 out into new classes. Typically, in C#, you would give these classes an interface and have `MyClass` take each of these interfaces as a dependency. E.g.

```C#
public interface IFooClassProvider
{
    FooClass CreateFooClass(MyContainer container, int d, int e, int f);
}

public interface IMyContainerProvider
{
    MyContainer CreateMyContainer(int a, int b, int c);
}

public MyClass
{
    private IMyContainerProvider _myContainerProvider;
    private IFooClassProvider _fooClassProvider;

    public MyClass(IMyContainerProvider myContainerProvider, IFooClassProvider fooClassProvider)
    {
        _myContainerProvider = myContainerProvider;
        _fooClassProvider = fooClassProvider;
    }
    ...
    public bool MyMethod(int a, int b, int c, out FooClass foo)
    {
       var someContainer = _myContainerProvider.CreateMyContainer(a,b,c);

       foo = _fooClassProvider.CreateFooClass(someContainer,1,2,3);

       ...
       return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Hopefully the 'real' implementations of the interfaces are obvious. In order to perform your test, you can then create mocks for each of these interfaces, e.g. `new Mock<IFooclassProvider>()` and pass them into the constructor for `MyClass`. In your unit test you can `Setup` the `IMyContainerProvider` mock to provider a specific container instance that you create in your unit test. You can then `Verify` that the `IFooClassProvider` mock's method was called with the specific container.

E.g.

```
var mockFooClassProvider = new Mock<IFooClassProvider>();
var mockMyContainerProvider = new Mock<MyContainerProvider>();

var myKnownContainer = new MyContainer(...);
mockMyContainerProvider.Setup(m => m.CreateMyContainer(It.IsAny<int>, ...))
    .Returns(myKnownContainer);

var myClass = new MyClass(mockMyContainerProvider.Object, mockFooClassProvider.Object);

FooClass fooClass;
myClass.MyMethod(..., out fooClass);

mockFooClassProvider.Verify(m => m.CreateFooClass(myKnownContainer, It.IsAny<int>(),...);
```

This answer is taking things to an extreme for such a simple situation, but I figure the example in the question was a simplified version of some more complex code. Separation of responsibilities in this fashion quickly simplifies code into short testable segments.